# Why Java doesn't allow me to add subclass istances?

Tags: java, hashmap, wildcard

I have a problem in a Java project.
The code where error born is the following:

```java
HashMap<String, LinkedList<? extends User>> signedUpUsers =
               new HashMap<>(Map.of(
                       "Administrator", new LinkedList<Administrator>(),
                       "Employee", new LinkedList<Employee>(),
                       "Customer", new LinkedList<Customer>()));
       for (String userName : userNameList)
       {
           userPropertyValue = usersProperties.getProperty(userName).split(",");
           String password = userPropertyValue[0].replaceAll("\\s", "");
           String role = userPropertyValue[1].replaceAll("\\s", "");
           if (role.equals("Administrator"))
           {
               signedUpUsers.get("Administrator").add(new Administrator(userName, password));
           }
           else if (role.equals("Customer"))
           {
               signedUpUsers.get("Customer").add(new Customer(userName, password));
           }
           else
           {
               signedUpUsers.get("Employee").add(new Employee(userName, password));
           }
       }
```

It gives me an error when I try to add new elements in each list of hashmap, when I create instances, intellij tells me: 
**Required type: capture of ? extends User 

Provided: Customer (or Employee or Administrator)** 
But why, if **Customer**, **Employee** and **Administrator** are all subclasses of **User**?

What I should change? My intention is to have an HashMap which contains all signed up users (I saved them in a .properties file which is corrected red because I saw that), where keys are roles of users (Administrators, Employees and Customers), and the value of each key is a LinkedList of each user with that role.
I also tried to use **super** instead of **extends**, but in that case I solve this error, but a new error appear in creating the hashmap with Map.of() (because Administrator, Customer and Employee aren't superclass of User).
The code works if I have 3 different lists declared directly with 3 roles objects, but I wanted the hashmap because I want to return the whole signed up users divided by their role.

Thanks to all, I hope I was clear in explaining.

Comment: `? extends User` means that the actual type could be a subclass of `User`, e.g. `Admininistrator`. Imagine you'd actually have a `List<Administrator>` and the compiler would allow you to add _any_ user, including `Customer`. Since the lists seem to only be accessed inside your code it might be safe to cast them, e.g. `((List)signedUpUsers.get("Administrator")).add(new Administrator(...)` (the cast to a raw type is needed since the compiler won't allow to cast to `List<Administrator>` directly - supress the resulting warning if you're sure the cast will be safe).

Comment: Btw, is there a need for those subclasses if you have the role already?

Comment: Thank you guys, @Thomas , your solution made the program work without errors. I didn't thought about that cast. For the other question, I made those subclasses of abstract User class because each role has a lot of different features, which I'll implement as methods; signed up users I read from .properties are the ones already signed up from past configurations (new ones will be added), and professor forced us to use these .properties files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the compiler error has been covered in @Thomas's comment: To the compiler, `signedUpUsers.get("Administrator")` is a `LinkedList<? extends User>`, not knowing that under the `"Administrator"` key, you stored a `LinkedList<Administrator>` (and not e.g. a `LinkedList<Employee>`, so the compiler does not allow adding an `Administrator`.

Your `signedUpUsers` variable shows some significant generics over-engineering. You declare

```
HashMap<String, LinkedList<? extends User>> signedUpUsers =
           new HashMap<>(Map.of(
                   "Administrator", new LinkedList<Administrator>(),
                   "Employee", new LinkedList<Employee>(),
                   "Customer", new LinkedList<Customer>()));
```

I suggest to change that to

```
HashMap<String, LinkedList<User>> signedUpUsers =
           new HashMap<>(Map.of(
                   "Administrator", new LinkedList<User>(),
                   "Employee", new LinkedList<User>(),
                   "Customer", new LinkedList<User>()));
```

You might ask "But now I don't have the type safety that I can only store `Administrator` instances under the `"Administrator"` key." But that type safety also wasn't possible with the first version (at run-time, the `LinkedList<Administrator>` is just a LinkedList and will happily accept any `Object`, and at compile-time `LinkedList<? extends User>` will not allow adding anything).

If you want type safety for the lists, throw away the `Map` approach, and create a class `UserList`:

```
public class UserList {
    private List<Administrator> administrators;
    private List<Employee> employees;
    private List<Customer> customers;
    // add constructor, getters, adders etc. here
}
```

This will easily give the desired type safety.